# Opening Text Files Within ListView in Android

Tags: android, file, listview, android-edittext, fileinputstream

I am working on a simple word processing app, and I'm close to the point of being able to release it, except that I have one problem. When I click on an item in a ListView that displays the file names of all the text files the user has created with my app, I would like to open the file that corresponds with the item name, and place the text from that file inside the main EditText that the user uses to input data. However, when the item is clicked, nothing happens. Here is my code for that action.

```
    filesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String itemName = filesListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    FileInputStream fis;
                    String content = null;

                    try {
                        fis = openFileInput(itemName);
                        byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];

                        while (fis.read(input) != -1) {
                            content += new String(input);

                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    textEntryEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textEntryEditText);
                    textEntryEditText.setText(content);
                }
            });
```

Please help. Thanks!

EDIT: SOLVED, check my Answer to see what I did.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the focusable of your listView items.Set the focusable to false for the editText in the ListView.

Comment: Try adding a toast message to see if the click functionality is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the file or path object from the Listview adapter not file name.
when using openFileInput(String) method it creates or get the file from application files folder not from that file location. so use BaseAdapter and get File object using getItem(int) method

Comment: like File file=(File)listview.getAdapter().getItem(position);

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using any a dapter for binding data to your listView,
So in custom adapter class

```
if(convertView==null){
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setTag(R.string.fileName, array.get(position).getfileName());
}else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
```

then on item click try to fetch file name like this

```
fileName = view.getTag(R.string.fileName).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved it. After several hours of tears, rage, and frustration, I finally solved it, lol. But thank you everyone who responded. As for anyone else who has a similar problem, here's what I did.

```
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String itemName = filesListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    StringBuffer fileRead = new StringBuffer("");

                        try {
                            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(getDir("FOLDER", Context.MODE_APPEND), itemName));
                            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
                            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                            String readString = bufferedReader.readLine();

                            while (readString != null) {
                                fileRead.append(readString);
                                readString = bufferedReader.readLine();
                            }
                            fileInputStream.close();
                            inputStreamReader.close();
                            bufferedReader.close();
                            textEntryEditText.setText(fileRead);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }


            });
```

My previous method of using the openFileInput was flawed, because I was trying to locate the file inside the default directory that openFileInput looks in, which is not where my file was. After, I tried referencing it directly, and found out that openFileInput does not allow this. So, I eventually tried just making a new FileInputStream, and telling it to make a new File object that uses the getDir method to reference the directory FOLDER, and the name of the file as determined by itemName. Hopefully this helps other who were struggling as I was, so that they don't have to suffer like I did. Thanks again to those who responded, even if I didn't use your advice!